Sending email with small attachment then email API giving response but if i send email with large size of attachment then API is not wait for response
If A am sending emails with a small attachment, the email API gives a response. However, if I send an email with large attachment, the API is not waiting for a response. I tried with timeout, but that is not helping. I am sending emails with attachments of up to  25 MB.
With large attachments it returns the response immediately, with no success. I tried from that API directly that works but from my code it is not waiting for response.
 public static async Task<string> SendEmail1(HttpContextBase contextBase, Email email)
        {
            string status = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                    string Token = await GetVendorToken(contextBase, vendorCredentialDetails);

                    HttpClient client;
                    string baseAddress = EHRAppSettingsDictionary.GetKeyValue("abc");
                    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                    handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                    client = new HttpClient(handler);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue(SharedConstants.StringWithQualityHeaderValue));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(SharedConstants.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", Token);
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                    string callingAddress = "api/EMAIL/SendEmail";
                    HttpResponseMessage VendorDetailsResponse = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(callingAddress, email).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (VendorDetailsResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        status = "Success";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        status = "Error : Integration not enabled.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    status = "Error : Integration not enabled.";
                }               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle general exceptions here
                status = $"Error: {ex.Message}";
            }
            return status;
        }


There is a request limit size on asp.net which is 30MB, to overcome this you can use following attributes :
[RequestSizeLimit(`int_value`)]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]


Hi there, in MVC we can do the same thing in maxRequestLength in web config but this solution is also not helping to me
